# Frama-c verification (From decimal to binary function)

Tags: frama-c

i'm trying to verify this in frama-c. I don't understand why the post-condition can't be verified. Can someone help me , please? 
I initially made ​​an axiomatic with a base case and an inductive case. The problem is that the post-condition is not verified. All the loop invariant are true.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*@ axiomatic ToBinary {
logic integer tobinary{L}(integer n)
reads n;
axiom binary1{L} :
\forall integer n;
(n == 0) ==> tobinary(n) == 0;
axiom binary2{L} :
\forall integer n;
(n > 0 ) ==> tobinary(n) == n%2 + 10*tobinary(n/2);
 }
*/

/*@ 
requires n >= 0;
assigns \nothing;
ensures \result == tobinary(n);
*/

int decimal_binary(int n)  /* Function to convert decimal to binary.*/
{
int rem, i=1, binary=0;

/*@
loop assigns n,rem,i,binary;
loop invariant 1 <= i <= i*10 ;
loop invariant 0 <= binary; 
*/

while (n!=0)
{
rem=n%2; 
n/=2;
binary+=rem*i;
i*=10;
}
return binary;
}
```

Comment: I expect that you are going to have more difficult follow-up questions, and eventually it may be that the post-condition is not verified because of the difficulty provers have to reason about arithmetic, but for this question it is simple: the post-condition is not proved because it does not result from the invariant. Your invariant says only that `1 ≤ i ≤ i*10` and `0 ≤ binary`. That may be true (in the case of the first one, it's a long way of saying that 1 ≤ i), but it's not strong enough to conclude that when the loop ends the situation `\result == tobinary(n);` has been reached.

Comment: The correct invariant to use would express that part of the conversion has been done, so that it's true before entering the loop when no work has been done, and that it shows that one more iteration does some more work, so that when exiting the loop, the entire conversion has been done. You need to do this on simpler examples first to understand how to write invariants that allow to prove the intended post-conditions. How about https://github.com/pascal-cuoq/wp-exercises/blob/master/incr.i or https://github.com/pascal-cuoq/wp-exercises/blob/master/compare.i ?

Comment: You also need an upper bound on `n` in order for the program to **really** have the property you want, but as long as you do not check for overflows in `binary+=rem*i` and `i*=10` this should not be what prevents you from proving the post-condition.

Comment: Thank you for responding  @PascalCuoq . I think I did it. I added this loop invariants:                                                                                     `loop invariant i >=1; `                                                                                 `loop invariant \forall int n ; (n==0)==> binary == 0 || \forall int n ; (n>0)==> binary == tobinary(n);`                                                         Frama-c is able to verify that but only when RTE and invariant are checked. Is this a problem?